# Is there anything like value labels of PSPP in Execl?

Tags: excel

I wonder if Excel 2013 has something that will represent number inputs as pre-set labels.

like input 1 in cell A1 but shows as "Computer Science" in the same cell, input 2 shows as "Computer Engineering" 
, something like that.

Sorry if my question is unclear, I don't good at english and maybe that's why I can't find my solution on google. 
Someone familiar with pspp might easier to understand what i am talking about

Comment: So you want to enter a numeral into cell A1 and have it DISPLAY as a predefined text string?

Comment: Oh sorry. I have some of answers now, both your method and VBA. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we want to enter a number between **1** and **92** in cell **A1** and have the corresponding element be displayed in the cell.  Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Dim I As Long, DQ As String
   DQ = Chr(34)
   I = Range("A1").Value - 1

   ary = Array("Hydrogen", "Helium", "Lithium", "Beryllium", "Boron", "Carbon", _
      "Nitrogen", "Oxygen", "Fluorine", "Neon", "Sodium", "Magnesium", "Aluminium", _
      "Silicon", "Phosphorus", "Sulfur", "Chlorine", "Argon", "Potassium", "Calcium", _
      "Scandium", "Titanium", "Vanadium", "Chromium", "Manganese", "Iron", "Cobalt", "Nickel", _
      "Copper", "Zinc", "Gallium", "Germanium", "Arsenic", "Selenium", "Bromine", _
      "Krypton", "Rubidium", "Strontium", "Yttrium", "Zirconium", "Niobium", "Molybdenum", _
      "Technetium", "Ruthenium", "Rhodium", "Palladium", "Silver", "Cadmium", "Indium", "Tin", _
      "Antimony", "Tellurium", "Iodine", "Xenon", "Caesium", "Barium", "Lanthanum", "Cerium", _
      "Praseodymium", "Neodymium", "Promethium", "Samarium", "Europium", "Gadolinium", _
      "Terbium", "Dysprosium", "Holmium", "Erbium", "Thulium", "Ytterbium", "Lutetium", "Hafnium", _
      "Tantalum", "Tungsten", "Rhenium", "Osmium", "Iridium", "Platinum", "Gold", "Mercury", _
      "Thallium", "Lead", "Bismuth", "Polonium", "Astatine", "Radon", "Francium", "Radium", _
      "Actinium", "Thorium", "Protactinium", "Uranium")

   Range("A1").NumberFormat = DQ & ary(I) & DQ & ";;;"
End Sub
```

[image]

 The value in **A1** has not changed, only the display.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: So this is a VBA. To be honest, this is the first time i see something like this. Much obliged

Answer (score 0):

The "conventional" solution would be to have a helper column and a lookup. Thus you might enter `1` in A1 and `Computer Science` would show in say B1 - with ColumnA possibly hidden after data entry.

The "comprehensive" solution is to use something like VBA - that will substitute what is entered into say A1 according to set rules such as "If `1` replace with `Computer Science`".

A "midway" solution would be Conditional Formatting, with a series of rules of the kind `Cell Value = 1` to trigger a Custom Format of `"Computer Science"`.

However, Excel is a spreadsheet program designed for number crunching. Such 'substitutions' are really better suited to a word processing package. In a spreadsheet if the applicable range for such 'transliterations' is not confined the rest of the spreadsheet functionality and most of its power would be severely crippled.

Ten CF rules to cope with ten labels is viable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I once learned something like Match and Index Is that what you called VBA?

Comment: @AwesomeCat No. VBA is custom programming for Excel automation. INDEX/MATCH is referring to worksheet functions/formulas.

Comment: Thanks again you two. @ExcelHero and pnuts

Answer (score 0):

Four labels can be done using Number Formatting. Besides the limited number of labels, this method also has the drawback that the numeric codes are not strictly assignable as you have described.

To see what can be done this way, apply the following Custom Number Format to a range of cells:

```
"Computer Science";"Computer Engineering";"Physical Science";"Biology"
```

Now when a value is entered into any of the cells in that range, here is what happens:

- If the value is POSITIVE, 'Computer Science' is displayed.
- If the value is ZERO, 'Physical Science' is displayed.
- If the value is NEGATIVE, 'Computer Engineering' is displayed.
- if the value is any TEXT, 'Biology' is displayed.

But that is it. No more than four labels can be configured this way.

If you reallay want to do this, the best solution is a VBA routine to translate custom codes to text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can finally say that there's no way I can do that.